# global variable for poor man's dependency injection in parse cloud code

Tags: parse-platform

I would like a variable to be shared among the various modules that I use for my cloud code.
For example, I was hoping I would be able to do the following:

In main.js, I would have the following:

```
  Env = 'prod';
  var Foo = require('cloud/foo.js').Foo;
```

Then in foo.js, I'd want to be able to access the value of Env

```
console.log("environment is: " + Env);
```

This does not work when deployed on Parse, but it does work if I run this in node.js.

Essentially, what I am looking for is a poor man's way to do dependency injection to allow me to easily test my cloud code in a local environment using node.js.

In the case above, Env would store the information that differs whether the cloud code executes in production (as a cloud function in Parse) or in a test (in node.js run locally).
[In the simple example above, I set Env to prod in main.js, and I'd set it to 'test' in my test script.]

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: I generally use two Parse environments for Dev/Prod. That way, I can use a config module that checks against the current Parse application id (Parse.applicationId in cloud code).

How are you calling you Parse server locally? Could you use a node env variable locally when starting your server and check on its existence in your main.js?

Comment: I'm actually doing as you suggest -- use a module that checks against the current Parse application id to tell which environment I am running against. It makes sense to do it that way. However, I'd still like to know why cloud code does not allow global variables to be seen across modules. This works in node.js.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure why, but in case you're not aware, Parse's Cloud Code environment is not a full node.js environment (e.g., you can't use npm packages) so that may affect it.